# CMS Layout Problem

Tags: html, content-management-system

I made a small page (http://www.ovlu.li) using CMS Made Simple (http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/). It looks more or less okay in all browser, but the problem is, if a resize the window to a smaller size, sometimes the layout of the subnavigation layer is destroyed. Instead of getting smaller, all the elements are ordered more or less randomly. Any hints why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is most likely because you are using a fixed width for the main container of your page. If you used the percentage instead, it should not behave that way. However, percent-based layouts are very rare.

Comment: as far as i know i used percentage to define the width of the main container

Comment: @Sebi: I think your main container is `pagewrapper` but i could not find any width defined there.

Comment: ah i thought i was 'clear'. Pagewrapper is defined in a stylesheet like this:

div#pagewrapper {
/* min max width, IE wont understand these, so we will use java script magic in the <head> */
 max-width: 99em;
 min-width: 60em;
/* now that width is set this centers wrapper */
 margin: 0 auto;
 //background-color: #ffffff;
background: #383838;
// color: black;
color: #ffffff;
}

Comment: @Sebi: you are using max-width but still `width` alone is missing so it is not percent based layout.

Comment: ok thanks. but then it is a bigger problem then just defining a width there in percent, right?

Comment: @Sebi: You can try out both percent based and fixed on and see the difference for yourself :) Finally there are sits using percent based layouts too.

Comment: yes but i was talking about if it is enough to only set there in this style definition a width attribute.
but your right, ill just try it ;)